# How to access results from extractall on a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe `df` in which the column `df.Type` has dimension information about physical objects. The numbers appear inside a text string which I have successfully extracted using this code:

```
dftemp=df.Type.str.extractall("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)").astype(float)
```

But now, the problem is that results appear as:

```
0
Unit    match   
5       0   0.02
        1   0.03
6       0   0.02
        1   0.02
7       0   0.02
```

...

How can I multiply these successive numbers (e.g. 0.02 * 0.03 = 0.006) and insert the result into the original dataframe df as a new column, say df.Area for each value of df.Type?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: Further searching reveals that I need to learn how to work with multi-indices.  Maybe I will be the first to answer my own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and then [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) along axis=1 like

```
print (dftemp.unstack().prod(axis=1))
```

then if I'm not mistaken, `Unit` is the name of the index in `df`, so I would say that

```
df['Area'] = dftemp.unstack().prod(axis=1)
```

should create the column you look for.

With an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Type':['bla 0.03 dddd 0.02 jjk','bli 0.02 kjhg 0.02 wait']},
                   index=pd.Index([5,6],name = 'Unit'))

df['Area'] = (df.Type.str.extractall("([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)").astype(float)
                .unstack().prod(axis=1))

print (df)
                         Type    Area
Unit                                    
5      bla 0.03 dddd 0.02 jjk  0.0006
6     bli 0.02 kjhg 0.02 wait  0.0004
```